# gpsvc consuming ldap ports?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, domain-controller

I have an odd issue with my Group Policy service on one of my domain controllers.

For some reason the gpsvc service within one of my svchosts is consuming a huge number of ports. The destination port is always to one of my DCs on the 389 LDAP port. The source ports can potentially be such a long list as to consume all available ports on the system. This generally starts causing problems around a few thousand open ports.

When we start having problems there is a specific path referenced in the 1058 errors in the event log, always a specific group policy ini file.

There doesn't appear to be any genuine content. Searching through the associated folder gives no content other than a couple template files, registry.pol, GptTmpl and the GPT ini file.

Should I go ahead and axe this policy or is there some additional debugging I need to look at? If so, where?

EDIT:

This policy is referenced in System->Policies in ASDI edit, is not included under the group policy management tools and only exists in the sysvol folder of one of my two DCs. The system having problems does not have a copy of this folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was corrected by [KB2561285](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2561285).